# $F = [P, Q]$ not conservative on $D$ but $P_y = Q_x$ on $D$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Stewart - Calculus

---

[image]

---

1. If all the assumptions hole but $D$ is not open and simply connected, is $F$ necessarily not conservative?

If so, why? Also, please give an example.

If not, please give an example where the conclusion still holds.

2. If all the assumptions hold but $P_x$ or $Q_y$ is not continuous, is $F$ necessarily not conservative?

If so, why? Also, please give an example.

If not, please give an example where the conclusion still holds.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the example defined on $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{0\}$
\begin{align}
F(x,y)= \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\mathbf{i} + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\mathbf{j}.
\end{align}
Observe
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
\end{align}
but 
\begin{align}
\int_C F\cdot ds \neq 0
\end{align}
where $C$ is the unit circle.